# Identificador de proceso

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en MVC bajo ASP.Net.

¿Tengo algún número de proceso distinto por cada "request" que haga?

Necesitaría identificar cada solicitud que se hace al server desde el browser.

No me sirve `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id` porque me devuelve siempre el mismo numero, cuando hago 2 requests desde dos pestañas distintas.

Comment: Normalmente es el mismo proceso el que atiende las solicitudes, por eso estás obteniendo un solo ID. El proceso IIS se encarga de gestionar dichos procesos de aplicación (app pool) y determina (en base a las solicitudes, timeouts, etc.) si crea nuevos procesos o los "pone a dormir". La pregunta sería, ¿para qué necesitas ese ID de proceso? Durante la vida de una aplicación cambiará en distintas ocasiones y no vuelve a "reciclarse" dicho ID; por lo tanto no es un dato "significativo" (en mi opinión).

Comment: En mi app cada request larga una secuencia de proceso en mi servidor y esos procesos pueden ser variables (cargados por reflection) necesitaría "logear" esa secuencia de procesos y en ese log saber cuales fueron los que se ejecutaron en una misma solicitud desde el cliente.

Comment: Sigo pensando igual; el ID no sirve de mucho si se lanza y, después de hacer su trabajo, se destruye. ¿No sería mejor guardar (en dicho log que mencionas) cuál proceso se ejecutó (nombre) y qué parámetros recibió para dicha ejecución (p.ej. un número de sesión o id de cliente conectado)? Si tales procesos son variables (como mencionas), entonces haciendo algo así tendrías el "panorama" de ejecución de una sola sesión.

Comment: bien, como asignarías ese numero de sesión o id de cliente? Yo queria hacer eso pero centralizado en el server.

Comment: Necesitas generar dicho ID en el archivo `Global.asax`. Tienes que hacerlo ahí sino se generará un ID por cada request del cliente (algo que te causará problemas); revisa esta pregunta / respuesta en SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/20350327/1732224

Comment: yo tengo algo parecido y lo que hago es que por cada peticion en el controller que resive la petición crea un `guid` de tracking que se pasa como parámetro en cada petición que este haga, es manual pero me permite loggear todos los mensajes entre capas internas, procesos asincrónicos e inclusive en algunas interfaces que consumimos lo enviamos como referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentacion de [HttpContext.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx) esta es por `request` por lo que en el `Global.Asax` podrías agregar código para almacenar un `Guid` y consumirlo después.

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["__IdProceso"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```